# What files are accessed often?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, logging, disk-activity

Our antivirus scans every file every time it's accessed.  We've been invited to provide directory paths on our workstations where "safe" and vigorous disk/IO activity occurs (compiling, for example -- we're a software development shop), so that we can exclude those paths from the OnAccess scans.  The exclusions will be created on a per-directory basis (sub-directories can be optionally excluded).

What tool can I use to tell me what directories on my workstation are serving the most file access requests while I'm working (the virusscan tool won't give me this information)?

Ideally (but not necessarily), I'm looking for something that will generate a summary report when it's finished: "This directory was REALLY active.  This directory was a bit LESS active."  That sort of thing.

I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple, you could do this with [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Don't forget to check out **Tools** > **File Summary** > **Folder** as that's the summary you want.

---

If you want to get your hands dirty, the more advanced [XPerf](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pigscanfly/xperf-a-new-tool-in-the-windows-sdk) tool from the WPT can help you...

Be sure to read the online documentation and the command line help.

Answer (score 0):

For what you want, you’ll need to use Windows’ [File Auditing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399) functionality; *Performance and Maintenance* includes graphing features.